# Facebook: how can I control what I see from a page I liked on my timeline?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-timeline, facebook-like

I like the page [Amazing Places on Earth](https://www.facebook.com/thousandamazingplacesonearth) on Facebook. They used to post several pictures every day that were beautiful and inspiring. Then suddenly, they started posting only silly links from a site. After a while I realized they were probably a spammer who got a lot of followers and then tried to convert that to page hits.

When I went to their page to unlike them, I saw that they have still been posting photos after all! But for some reason, Facebook is choosing not to show them on my timeline; only the spammy link posts! How can I let Facebook know that I want to see the photos (and not the links)?